# Codeigniter - How to redirect to a controller with javascript variable?($this->load->view() not working)

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, tcpdf

I'm trying to convert current html page to pdf using TCPDF. I use Ajax to pass the html code to CreatePDF controller, but not sure why the "pdfreport" view cannot be open.

In my controller CreatePDF:

```
public function pdf() {
  $this->load->helper('pdf_helper'); //tcpdf helper file
  $HTMLInfo = $this->input->post('HTMLInfo'); //get html code from view
  $data['HTMLInfo'] = $HTMLInfo;
  $this->load->view('pdfreport', $data);
}
```

In View I have a "PDF" button, when click:

```
$('#pdf').click(function(){
  $.ajax({//ajax call
     type: 'post', 
     url: '<?php echo base_url('CreatePDF/pdf'); ?>',
     data: {'HTMLInfo': document.getElementById('repTable').outerHTML}, 
     success: function (data) {
     }
   });
});
```

If I replace $data['HTMLInfo'] with html code, and call CreatePDF directly, there's no problem to load the pdf page.

If I use:

```
$HTMLInfo = 'TEST'; 
<input type="button"  onClick="location.href = '<?php echo site_url("CreatePDF/pdf/{$HTMLInfo}"); ?>'" value="HTMLInfo" />
```

There's also no problem to print out the "TEST" in pdf, but how to use "document.getElementById('repTable').outerHTML" instead of "TEST"?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: you need to send true or false from controller and check it in your success function if true then location.herf="url"; you can't load view in ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to redirect in your controller function if you try to load the view isn't work because ajax is background Task.

**Example**

```
public function pdf() {
      $this->load->helper('pdf_helper');
      $HTMLInfo = $this->input->post('HTMLInfo');
      if($HTMLInfo != "") {
        $urisegment = base64_encode($HTMLInfo);
        redirect("controller_name/function_name/'".$urisegment."'");
      }
    }

    public function get_html($html){
        $data = base64_decode($html);
        $this->load->view('pdfreport', $data);
    }
```